# Parallel execution of jenkins builds in different directories

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I use Jenkinse(file) Piplines and want to run multiple build steps in parallel (different constants for example - these can't be passed to the compiler, source code has to be changed by a script).

this could look something like that:

```
stage('Build') {
    steps {
        parallel(
            build_default: {
                echo "WORKSPACE: ${WORKSPACE}"

                bat 'build.bat'
            },
            build_remove: {
                echo "WORKSPACE 2: ${WORKSPACE}"

                // EXAMPLE: only to test interference
                deleteDir() // <- this would be code changes
            }
        )
    }
}
```

This is not working since all the code is deleted before compilation is done. I want to run both steps in parallel like jenkins does it (creating multiple temp directories `@2` and so on) when 2 builds run in parallel (triggered by button presses for example).

The only thing I found out so far is to create temp dirs myself in the working dir and copy the sourcecode to them and work there. But I'm looking for a nicer/more automatic solution. (when using the node command I have the same problems since I only have one node)

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259039/how-to-re-use-previously-created-workspace-across-stages/44284131