# Why Bitbucket souce code repository not getting cloned using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using latest Jenkins in my Linux box. I am trying to clone a Bitbucket repository and checkout master branch using Jenkins pipeline. What I am trying to achieve is, after getting my source code cloned, I can make use of it and proceed with build. Below is my code;

```
node { 
    stage('Build') {

            git branch: 'master',
                credentialsId: '12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123',
                url: 'https://username@bitbucket.org/username/test.git'
    }
    stage('Test') {
        sh """pwd""" 
    }
}
```

and below is my console output;

```
Started by user User
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] git
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pipeline/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://username@bitbucket.org/username/test.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://username@bitbucket.org/username/test.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.32.0'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials bitbucket_token_1
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://username@bitbucket.org/username/test.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision ae8839d74d91d4ae28ba37a4ec91fa2265058b75 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f ae8839d74d91d4ae28ba37a4ec91fa2265058b75 # timeout=10
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git branch -D master # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b master ae8839d74d91d4ae28ba37a4ec91fa2265058b75 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Initial commit"
 > git rev-list --no-walk ae8839d74d91d4ae28ba37a4ec91fa2265058b75 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] sh
+ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pipeline
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

When I cd to `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pipeline` I can see nothing. Why is this happening?

Comment: **When** do you check there? Jenkins cleans up its work directories once the job has finished and since your `test` stage simply runs `pwd` it will finish very quickly.

Comment: Also you can see, that the clone was successful, since it successfully checked out a commit with the message `Commit message: "Initial commit"`

Comment: @JoachimSauer is there any way to disable cleanup?

Comment: @dunni , yeah, I got it

Comment: @JoachimSauer , I have added `ls -ltr` instead of pwd, but its showing `+ ls -ltr
total 0`

Comment: Seems like [this could be relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259039/how-to-re-use-previously-created-workspace-across-stages).